# How to query records of public azure dns zones via resource graph?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-graph

I try to utilize Azure Resource Graph to get all records from Public DNS zones, but I query `dnsresources`- oder `resources`- table its only containing private dns zones. Does anybody have an idea which table to query to get the records?

I only got this query to get all public dns zones but there are no records whether as properties nor as dedictated resource type.

```
resources
| where ['type'] == "microsoft.network/dnszones"
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to query records of public azure dns zones via resource graph?

To query the `Public DNS` zone records using resource graph, you can use the below query.

```kotlin
    resources
    | where type == "microsoft.network/dnszones"
    | where properties.zoneType == "Public"
    | extend NameServers = properties.nameServers
    | project ['id'],name,NameServers,resourceGroup,['type']
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use `PowerShell` to check the records in the `Public DNS` zone.

```
    $rg= Get-AzResourceGroup
    foreach($RG in $rg){
    $Rgname = $RG.ResourceGroupName
    $Zone = Get-AzDnsZone -ResourceGroupName $Rgname
    $Zone
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I want to get the A or MX records